# tail command with dynamic file parameter

Tags: linux, bash, tail

I am now using the tail command as below

show_log.sh:

```
LOGFILE=`ls -1 -r ./myservice.log.????????.?????? | head -n 1`
tail -v -f -s 1 -n  100 ${LOGFILE}
```

to monitor the log file.

The problem with it is that after each service restart, a new log file will be created, and the prior log file will be compressed. So the tail command stops working.

I need to change the script so that to continue tailing with the new file

Comment: You can probably use a script to get the newest file fitting the name pattern and set LOGFILE to that.

Comment: You could perhaps adjust your log rotation scheme to be compatible with tail's `-F` option (capital F), which does precisely what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way. ojblass with the capital F parameter suggestion helped.
Actually I created a link to the latest log file by the following command after each service restart:

```
ln -n service-blabla.log log_lnk
```

and changed the tail command like this:

```
tail -v -F -s 1 -n  100 log_lnk
```

Note the capital F in the tail command. Lowercase f doesn't work in this situation.

done.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve this, depending on what exactly you want to achieve.

## Answer 1: Your posted solution (with improvements)

While your posted solution would work, it would require you to actually set the symlink every time it changed, which would be annoying. Particularly since it looks like you are watching a service, so knowing when a log file will change may be difficult.

As a possible improvement to consider, you could put the call to create the sym link in a [watch](https://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) call. This would automatically move the sym link once a new file is created.

```
watch -t -n 1 'ln -s -f  $(ls -1vr service-blabla.log* | head -n 1) log_lnk' &> /dev/null &
```

This command will recreate the sym link every second, so you don't need to. Then you can run your tail like normal.

```
tail -v -F -s 1 -n  100 log_lnk
```

If you're going to be doing this often (I.e. after system restarts), I doubt you are going to want to be running the watch command every time. In that case, I would suggest creating a [cron job](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) or [its replacement timers](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) to automatically check and create the link at specified intervals.

## Answer 2: The one liner

The cleanest approach would be to loose the `-F` altogether and instead use `watch` to achieve the same effect.

```
watch -t -n 1 'tail -v -n 10  $(ls -1vr service-blabla.log* | head -n 1)'
```

This will output the last 10 lines of the last file `service-blabla.log*` when sorted "naturally". The display will be a little different than if using `tail -f`, but I think it's similar enough to be just about what you would want. We aren't creating a link here, so no need for a cron/timer or anything like that. Plus, it's a one-liner, so that's cool.

## Answer 3: The simpler approach

Of course, there is always a technically simpler, but slightly longer, solution. If I were to do this at 12 AM and didn't want to mess around with getting the watch call set up just right, I would probably just do this in a loop.

```
while true; do ln -s -f $(ls -1vr service-blabla.log* | head -n 1) log_lnk; sleep 1; done &
tail -v -F -s 1 -n  100 log_lnk
```

Oh yea, brute force to the rescue.